# How can I make the AppBar on Windows phone disappears/appear programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

On Windows phone, I can declare App bar in my page like this:

```
 <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
    ..
    </CommandBar>
 </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

My question is how can I programmatically make that app bar disappear and reappear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence *IsOpen* property opens/closes the AppBar (shows/hides secondary menu and labels), to hide completely the AppBar, I'm just seting *BottomAppBar* property to null just after remembering the old bar in variable. Then when I want to return my AppBar, I use that variable, sample code:

```cs
CommandBar previousBar;
private void HideBar()
{
    previousBar = BottomAppBar as CommandBar;
    BottomAppBar = null;
}

private void ShowBar()
{
    BottomAppBar = previousBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open and close the app bar programmatically [by setting the IsOpen property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.isopen.aspx). You can respond to the app bar being opened or closed by handling the Opened and Closed events.

```
if (this.BottomAppBar != null)
{
    this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get a reference to the Appbar in my Code behind in order to set the IsOpen Property?

Comment: AppBar is a Page object - this.BottomAppBar